# Whether the "take a little thing and turn it into a phenomenon" is equal to "turn a little thing into a phenomenon"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Advertisers and producers have developed a theory of "viral" marketing, which assumes that a great idea is self-distributing, and word of mouth can take a little thing and turn it into a phenomenon. (excerpt from Time Feb. 18,2017)

My question is: whether the "take a little thing" can be deleted? So may I say "take a little thing and turn it into a phenomenon" = "turn a little thing into a phenomenon"?

Why do not just say "turn a little thing into a phenomenon"? Is there any special meaning?

Comment: The fuller version emphasises the skills involved better. The adroit choice of which little thing can be turned into a phenomenon is strongly connoted.

Comment: That is completely up to you. "I walked to the store and bought milk." Should I instead say "I bought milk at the store", since it's obvious that I must've walked to the store to buy milk? It fully hinges on what you are trying to communicate. Is it important to communicate that you took a little thing (as opposed to being given a little thing, without being able to choose)?

Comment: English, even good English,   is not always about using the minimum number of words.

Answer (score -1):

There's no special meaning, but it's a question of style. The writer may possibly have been inspired by Meryl Streep's "Take your broken heart and turn it into art" (see https://exploringyourmind.com/take-broken-heart-turn-art/) or other similar phrases. It's a rhetorical device.

Comment: You could try googling "take a * and turn it into a *" to see the phrase in action.